# Where are you according to this riddle?

Tags: riddle

Go forward, and you'll arrive back. Go back, and you'll arrive back. Go west and you'll come from the east. Go east and you'll come from the west. Jump once and you black out, jump twice and you're back, but if dig, you're out in the black, never to come back!

Where are you?

**EDIT:**

I changed a part of the riddle to make it less difficult.